# How to create appdata folders for a service a in setup project (C#)

Tags: c#, service, installation, directory, appdata

I am trying to create folders for my C#-service that is being installed with the vs2010 installer/setup project. I have almost all of it working, but I can't figure out how to add the appdata folder. The difference to all other solutions I have found is that I am trying to install a service, not an application. Also, my service runs as a Local System user. The appdata service tries to access this folder:

C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\MyService\

This is the folder my service tries to access when I use this syntax:

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "MyService", "status.xml");
```

The setup project is configured to add the MyService folder to the "User's Application Data Folder", but that ends up C:\Users...... which my service cannot find.

Is there a good way to make my service and the installer use the same folder, preferable a folder that is meant for this kind of use (storing configuration and runtime status from my service)?

Comment: I gave up on using the Setup Project for creating my folders and had the service itself do it. With the above code, the path it uses is:
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\MyService
But in reality, the path being used is this:
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\MyService
I don't know how I should be able to make the Setup Project supply files for this particular service.